# Is the Taylor series of the $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ evaluated at $0$ converges pointwise (in the whole $\mathbb{R}$)?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion

I would like to solve this problem:

> Consider the $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ function which is $n$-times
>   differentiable for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
>
> Is it true that the Taylor series of the $f$ function evaluated at the
>   point $0$ converges pointwise (in the whole $\mathbb{R}$)?

---

#### What I've done so far:

1. By the definition of the pointwise convergence:
   $$
   \forall_{x \in \mathbb{R}} \forall_{\epsilon > 0} 
   \exists_{N \geq n_0} \exists_{n \geq N} |T_{n, f, 0}(x) - g| < \epsilon
   $$
   where $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is basically $f$. ***(am I right?)***
2. By the Lagrange Reminder Theorem:
   Let's pick an $a \in \mathbb{R}$. Because $f$ is differentiable $(n+1)$-times I can say that 
   $$
   \exists_{c \in (0;a)} R_{n,f,0} = \frac{f^{(n+1)}(c)}{(n+1)!}x^{n+1}
   $$
3. Because $R_{n,f,0} := T_{n, f, 0}(x) - f(x)$ I can say that:
   $$
   \forall_{x \in \mathbb{R}} \forall_{\epsilon > 0} 
   \exists_{N \geq n_0} \exists_{n \geq N} 
   |\frac{f^{(n+1)}(c)}{(n+1)!}x^{n+1}| < \epsilon
   $$
   which is not true because for a certain $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$, $\frac{f^{(n+1)}(c)}{(n+1)!}$ is not necessarily converging towards $0$. ***(or is it?)***
4. Therefore it is not true.

---

I am not sure if my reasoning is correct. I would be grateful for any feedback.

Comment: To show that a general statement is *not* true, you need an *example* in which the statement fails.

Comment: Well, for power series, pointwise convergence on $\Bbb R$ would imply uniform convergence on $[-A,A]$ for arbitrary $A>0$, which is a *very* strong result.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, so after I see in the 3. step that the statement cannot be true, I should look for an counterexample, right?

Comment: @moonnoon that's right. In other words, how do you *know* that it is *not necessarily* going to converge to $0$, unless you find an $f$ for which that won't converge.

Comment: It's actually possible that the Taylor series based at $0$ converges only at the point $0.$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, so I just need to find that counterexample as the **3.5** step. Thank you! How about the text in bold? Are these steps of my "proof" reasonable?

Comment: @moonnoon the steps are reasonable, but ultimately redundant once you have the counterexample.

Comment: @moonnoon ultimately, you just have to accept that none of the steps that go towards attempting to *prove* a statement do anything to disprove that statement, except perhaps that they might help you *find* a counterexample.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. Look at $f(x) = \dfrac{1}{1 + x^2}$. Its Taylor series at $x = 0$ is just a geometric series with finite radius of convergence.

Answer (score 3):

Furthermore, even if the Taylor series converges, it does not necessarily converge to $f(x)$.

*Counter-example:* Consider the function $f$ defined by:
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}\mathrm e^{-\tfrac1{x^2}}&\text{if } x\ne 0\\0&\text{if } x= 0\end{cases}$$

On can prove by induction on the order of derivation that $f^{(n)}(x)=P_n\Bigl(\dfrac1x\Bigr)\mathrm e^{-\tfrac1{x^2}}$, where $P_n\Bigl(\dfrac1x\Bigr)$ is a polynomial in $\dfrac1x$ with highest degree term $\;\dfrac{2^n}{x^{3n}}\;$ and $f^{(n)}(0)=0$. Hence its Taylor series at $0$ is the null series, which of course converges, but not to $\;\mathrm e^{-\tfrac1{x^2}}$.